# Without the mouse, how do I select a pattern and then drag it to expand it to other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a long pattern like this: [image] . I want to change the 0.2's to 0.1 like so [image]

With the mouse I would enter it in the first two cells and then drag it down like so [image] [image]

All the solutions online tell me to select all the cells and use CTRL+D, but that fills all the cells including the ones that were empty before, which is not the goal. **Does anyone know how to do this particular thing with just the keyboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type 0.1 in cell A1 and press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>** (to stay in the current cell)
2. Hold **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** and press **<kbd>↓</kbd>**
3. Press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>**
4. Hold **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** and press **<kbd>↓</kbd>** as many times as you need (**NB:** make sure you select an even number of rows)
5. Press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>**

Excel will duplicate the current clipboard selection as long as integer multiples of it *fit* into the selected range. Works in 2D as well. This seems to be the only restriction as compared to working with the fill handle and the mouse (where it will simply *fit* and *crop*). As an advantage though, you can 2D copy-paste multiples in one go, where as with the fill handle and mouse you have to first drag along the row, then drag along the column.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the answer that does exactly what I was looking for, thank you! @DavidPostill's answer was also quite useful though not as direct.

Answer (score 0):

#### Does anyone know how to do this particular thing with just the keyboard?

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> <kbd>Key</kbd>

> [image]

Source: [Excel Extend Selection Shortcuts - MS-Excel Tutorial](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-excel/extend-selection.html)

Comment: Hmm? It seems to be a question about "fill down", not just extending the selection.

Answer (score 0):

The EXACT thing you wish to do can be done as follows:

1. Of course, start at the "hard to get to" end and move back to the easy to get to end. That distinction might not exist in which case, just knuckle down and do it the hard way. You want to be at one end, however you do it, and hold down the `SHIFT` key while moving to the other end. If, say, you need to highlight (that's what it does, "select" in Excel-speak) A1:G23456, then A1 is the easy end to get to. So use `CTRL-G` to go to G23456, hold down `SHIFT`, and press `HOME` (so, `SHIFT-HOME`) to easily reach the far end of the block you need.

All the above means is that you have to assess the lie of the ground and adjust the details accordingly. If you needed the range C11847:G23456, it would simply be "hard" and that would be that... It will be what it will be. *(Actually, there'd be a workaround that would make even that pretty easy. More at the end.)*

2. So, once highlighted ("selected"), you just do a `Find and Replace` to replace the "2" character with the "1" character. You access that function with `CTRL-H`.

So, all done via the keyboard.

Many variations in each part are possible, as needed. Way too many possibilities exist to cover them exhaustively here. The trick is to be clever about how one chooses the way to highlight the range. Look for ways to use `GOTO` (`CTRL-G`) to get to hard to reach ends, then `HOME`, `END`, the `PAGEUP/PAGEDOWN` keys, and the arrow keys while holding down `SHIFT` to reach a distant, but amenable to those keys, end. And of course, in combination with `CTRL` (and even "SCROLL LOCK" as `DavidPostill` shows!).

So, the aforementioned trick. The idea here is to take a hard to select in the manners above, what one might call "physical" selection involving, sometimes, lots of scrolling, and replace it with a "work smarter, not harder" way.

One can Name a range and then select that range via the `Name Box` to the left of the formula bar. So, you need a Named Range, then a way to access that box and select it.

Press `CTRL-F3` to bring up the Named Range functionality. Press `ALT-N` to create a new name. Give it an appropriate name, then press `TAB` twice to reach its `Refers to` box. Type `=` and the range address. (You need it to be absolute, so use the dollar signs everywhere. Or, after typing it (maybe that's "C11847:G23456"), press `F2` to switch the kind of interaction you have in it from the arrow keys moving the selected cell around the underlying cell/sheet view to the arrow keys moving you about in the `Refers to` box. Now highlight all or parts of both halves of the address you typed and press `F4` to have Excel put the dollar signs in.) Save that by pressing `ENTER` and get out of the Named Range Manager by pressing `ESCAPE`.

So, you have a Named Range for this. Press `ALT-F3` to get right into the `Name Box`. It will be showing the address of the cell you had selected just then and that will be highlighted. Press the `DOWN ARROW` and move the selector from Name to Name until you reach the one you just created. Press `ENTER` to select it and your range will be selected on the grid screen. It should show the portion of the range that includes the active cell.

Now do that `Find and Replace`, or whatever else you needed to do, and it will be done to every cell in your range, as desired.

I mostly use that to select data entry cells I need cleared, then press `DELETE` to clear them all at once... and all of them:  no missing a couple and having that bite me later. Getting past not using the mouse, one can do this to create a range, selecting cells in a particular order, and when using it seeing that pressing `ENTER` will move you to the cells in that same order. So perhaps a data entry idea, or to move straight to and between certain critical cells that are hundreds of feet apart on the screen. I've probably used it half a dozen ways over the years. Easy to do with no mouse for your need. But if choosing a selection of noncontiguous cells and ranges using the mouse will be vastly easier.

Oh, and yes, as mentioned in the comment, `CTRL-D` realllllly isn't the thing you can use here.